# Is there an intermediate layer/cache between Kubernetes pod and Persistance volume, or does a pod access PV directly

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, persistent-volumes, glusterfs

Recently I ran into a strange problem. We have two pods running into an openshift cluster that shares a persistent volume (`GlusterFs`) between them.
Now for the sake of this explanation, let's assume one of the pods was ***PodA*** and the Other was ***PodB***, in this case, ***PodB*** was running for three months, there is automation in ***POdA*** which creates/updates files in the shared persistence volume and ***PodB*** reads it and perform some operation based on the input.

Now coming to the problem, whenever ***POdA*** created a new file in the shared PV it was visible and accessible from ***PodA***. However, there were a few files that ***PodA*** was updating periodically, but the change was not reflected in ***PodB***. So in ***PodB***, we could only see the old version of those files. To solve that problem, we have forcefully deleted   ***PodB***, and then openshift recreated it, and the problem was gone.

I thought in `PV` mechanism Kubernetes mount external storage/folder into the `pod` (container), and there is no intermediate layer or cache or something like that. From what we have experienced so far, it seems every container (or `pod`) creates a local copy of those files, or maybe there is a  cache in between (`PV` and `pod`),

I have searched about this on google and could not find a detailed explanation on how this `PV` mount works in Kubernetes , would love to know the actual reason behind this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no caching mechanism for PVs provided by Kubernetes, so the problem you are observing must be located in either the GlusterFS CSI driver or GlusterFS itself.

Comment: If it was a problem with GlusterFS, how come one of the existing pods was displaying it (the file) correctly(in PodA, we could see the change). It felt like it was a problem with PodB, which was running for three months.